# Like BrE's apparently idiosyncratic "drink-driving", does English have any other hyphenated constructions of the form "noun-verb"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, hyphenation, verb-phrases

As in title. I can think of many hyphenated constructions of other forms, such as

- *noun-adjective* (e.g. nut-safe, child-friendly, community-driven)
- *adjective-verb* (e.g. low-flying),
- *adverb-verb* (e.g. well-made), and
- *adjective-verb* (e.g. ready-made),

but cannot think of any others of the form *noun-verb*. A discussion arose in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/rzrioa/drink_driving_warning_on_back_of_beer_can/hs1mk6v/?context=8&depth=9), which prompted this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are. For example, [***punch-pulling***](https://www.lexico.com/definition/punch-pulling), [***life-threatening***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life-threatening) or [***pocket-picking***](https://www.google.com/search?q=pocket-picking&sxsrf=AOaemvL3xU8awmfdWC1V_-vvPuQjxNvcnw%3A1641810400319&source=hp&ei=4AncYY7HEcyUgQbf6qG4CQ&iflsig=ALs-wAMAAAAAYdwX8F-V5Jf4VCOtjuFs7b_c61cbwHh2&ved=0ahUKEwiOt8qt_Kb1AhVMSsAKHV91CJcQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=pocket-picking&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOg4ILhCABBCxAxDHARCjAjoICAAQgAQQsQM6CAguEIAEELEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToECAAQQzoFCAAQgAQ6BAguEEM6CgguEMcBEK8BEEM6DQguELEDEMcBENEDEEM6CQgAEEMQRhD5AToHCC4QsQMQQzoKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoLCC4QgAQQxwEQ0QM6BAgAEB5QAFirK2CrLmgAcAB4AIABowGIAdQNkgEEMS4xM5gBAKABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz). In these examples, the noun is the direct object of the verb. The particularity of ***drink-driving*** is that *drink* is describing the action of the verb *drive*, it is not its direct object. So it may be unique in this sense.

Here is a link where you can find plenty of more examples: [wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/wf---compound-adjectives-ending-in--ing).

PS: Thanks to a comment I must make clear that:  the noun cannot be the object in the compound, but by meaning, in a sentence it can be. It is the punch that is pulled, the life that is threatened etc., but the drink cannot be driven.

Comment: I would avoid talking in terms of direct object. In compounds like "life-threatening", "heart-breaking", "cost-cutting" etc. the noun happens to _correspond_ to the object in a syntactic construction, but it is not a direct object in the compound. These are morphological compounds, not syntactic constructions.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, that's what I meant. It cannot be the object in the compound, but by meaning, in a  sentence they can be. It is the punch that is pulled, the life that is threatened etc., whereas the drink cannot be driven. Sorry for not making it clear. Will edit

Comment: Well, the UK has *drug-driving* as well, which is not the same as drug-pushing.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, correct. But you will agree that it is not easy to find many other such instances.

Comment: What about roller-skating; dirt-biking; fence-sitting....

Comment: @Stuart I've suggested a tightening of the specification of the semantic relationship between N and V-inv/V-ed here, such that the subset 'V-ing while N/Ned' is targetted.